# Interrupt a drag&drop in progress

Tags: javascript, angular, drag-and-drop

I have an Angular7 application where I'm using native HTML Drag&Drop. When the dragged item enter in a specific area (catch with dragenter event), I want to force the interruption of the current drag operation.

But I could not find a way to do that in native JavaScript or Angular.

I put a `dragenter` event on the div of this specific area and tried many solutions when it trigger :

`preventDefault()` or `stopPropagation()` don't work and I also tried to simulate a mouseup and a keyboard (escape press) events with a dispatchEvent : `document.getElementById('interruptArea').dispatchEvent(AnEvent)`

That's all I tried, didn't find anything else. Do you know if there are a way to do this ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: What have you tried so far ? paste your code here please :)

Comment: I edited my main message. I didn't tried many solutions, as I didn't find many